# Removing '' buckets from elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-aggregation

How do I make elasticsearch `aggregation` to remove certain bucket keys from the aggregation result without modifying the `query` term. For example I want to remove `''` empty keys from the bucket list. Is there some sort of having clause that I can use?

My query is something like this

```json
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
        "name_match": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name_match",
            "min_doc_count": 2,
            "size": 20
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```json
{
    "hits": {
     ...
    },
    "aggregations": {
          "name_match": {
             "buckets": [
                {
                   "key": "A",
                   "doc_count": 136
                },
                {
                   "key": "B",
                   "doc_count": 16
                },
                {
                   "key": "",
                   "doc_count": 24
                }]
              }
    }
}
```

Wanted Result

```json
{
    "hits": {
     ...
    },
    "aggregations": {
          "name_match": {
             "buckets": [
                {
                   "key": "A",
                   "doc_count": 136
                },
                {
                   "key": "B",
                   "doc_count": 16
                }]
              }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It is possible using `exclude` parameter available in `terms aggregation`. This parameter takes array of keys which need to be excluded from buckets. To exclude specific keys, your aggregation should be rewritten as shown below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
        "name_match": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name_match",
            "exclude": [""],
            "min_doc_count": 2,
            "size": 20
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You can read about this topic [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values).

Hope this helps!